# Try to select insert in mysql db and get sqlerror 1205

Tags: mysql

I want to execute this query in mysql database:

```
INSERT INTO customerdata (CustomerID, ......)
        SELECT cd.CustomerID, ...
        FROM customerdata cd
        WHERE cd.Latest = 1
        AND cd.CustomerID IN
            (SELECT CustomerID
            FROM customerdata
            WHERE Active = 1 
            GROUP BY CustomerID
            HAVING (MAX(StatisticDate) < UTC_TIMESTAMP()));
```

But I've got "SQLError (1205): Lock wait timeout exceed; try restarting transaction". I read [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) "When selecting from and inserting into a table at the same time, MySQL creates a temporary table to hold the rows from the SELECT and then inserts those rows into the target table" and what's wrong?
*innodb_version: 1.1.8
protocol_version: 10
version: 5.5.28*

Comment: SELECT query was too heavy, after some changes it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your inserting too much record. Try executing start transaction first then execute your Insert Statement. Then commit the changes.